# Running a node script 'forever' in heroku (or aws) with no front end?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku

I have a requirement of running a node script (not app or dapp), which has no front -end files (html, css). This script will send transactions (call smart contract function) in regular intervals. the only constraint is that this script needs to run perpetually (forever) without stopping, unless a specific command is given by admin. Please do suggest how we could achieve this? Thanks.

PS: in case you have a better platform suggestion other than heroku, those are welcome as well with details. Tx.

Comment: Are you talking about cron-job type of functionality? eg. Execute after specified time interval?

Comment: this might not be what I'm looking for though it is a very good suggestion. the interval values change with every iteration and hence, I require any cloud computing solution (aws, heroku, google cloud) and the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Unix cron works fine for this kind of things. Just add a cron in your crontab with command :

**crontab -e**

Then just set your pattern and add a line with your command to launch, for example this will run each day at 3.00 AM:

**0 3 * * * /root/backup.sh**

Then don't forget to reload your cron process:

**sudo service cron restart**

Define your pattern here : https://crontab.guru/

Comment: this might not be what I'm looking for though it is a very good suggestion. the interval values change with every iteration and hence, I require any cloud computing solution (aws, heroku, google cloud) and the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

The good thing about kue is, that it gives you a UI where an admin can view the running, failed, jobs etc. Also, you can configure it to stop a job programmatically.